# What does the reset() method of Scanner do?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, user-input

I have a simple Java program using `java.util.Scanner` as follows:

```java
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Favorite_Number {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int X,sum = 0,rem = 0,t;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = s.nextInt();
        while(t!=0) {
            s.reset();  // <-- what does it do?
            X = s.nextInt();
            while (X > 0) {
                rem = X % 10;
                if (rem == 5) {
                    sum++;
                }
                X = X / 10;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
            sum = 0;
            t--;
        }

    }
}
```

What does `s.reset()` do? If I remove it, the program still works fine.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  That's all I did.  It resets the default delimiter, if it had been changed.  You didn't change it, so you don't need to reset.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reset()` is explained [here with examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-reset-method-in-java-with-examples/?tab=article)

and as per documents purpose stated as:

> On resetting a scanner **discards** all of its explicit state information **which may have been changed by *invocations of `useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)`, `useLocale(java.util.Locale)`, or `useRadix(int)`.***

Docs reference:
[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset--](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset--:%7E:text=scanner%20is%20closed-,reset,1.6,-SKIP%20NAVIGATION%20LINKS)